# Player.EventListener of SimpleExoPlayer is not working

Tags: android, exoplayer

I am playing video from URLs and I want to show a text when video starts playing. Text could be like "1 of 6".

I have added `Player.EventListener` but its not working.

```
  // Player Event Listener
Player.EventListener eventListener = new Player.EventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTimelineChanged(Timeline timeline, Object manifest) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTracksChanged(TrackGroupArray trackGroups, TrackSelectionArray trackSelections) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadingChanged(boolean isLoading) {
        progressBar.setVisibility(isLoading ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPlayerStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady, int playbackState) {
        if (playbackState == PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_SKIP_TO_NEXT) {
            Toast.makeText(VideoActivity.this, "next", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        if (playbackState == PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_SKIP_TO_PREVIOUS) {
            Toast.makeText(VideoActivity.this, "previous", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRepeatModeChanged(int repeatMode) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPlayerError(ExoPlaybackException error) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPositionDiscontinuity() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPlaybackParametersChanged(PlaybackParameters playbackParameters) {

    }
};
```

**Update**

**onCreate Method**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_video);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);

    presenter = new VideosPresenter(this);
    presenter.getVideoUrls();


    // 1. Create a default TrackSelector
    bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
    videoTrackSelectionFactory = new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter);
    trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(videoTrackSelectionFactory);

    // 2. Create a default LoadControl
    LoadControl loadControl = new DefaultLoadControl();

    // 3. Create the player
    player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this, trackSelector, loadControl);
    mediaDataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this, Util.getUserAgent(this, getString(R.string.app_name)), null);

    simpleExoPlayerView = findViewById(R.id.player_view);
    simpleExoPlayerView.requestFocus();
    simpleExoPlayerView.setPlayer(player);

    presenter = new VideosPresenter(this);
    player.addListener(eventListener);

}
```

**Initialisation**

```
    private void initializePlayer() {
    simpleExoPlayerView.requestFocus();
    TrackSelection.Factory videoTrackSelectionFactory =
            new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter);
    trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(videoTrackSelectionFactory);
    player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this, trackSelector);
    simpleExoPlayerView.setPlayer(player);

    MediaSource[] mediaSources = new MediaSource[urlList.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < urlList.size(); i++) {
        mediaSources[i] = buildMediaSource(Uri.parse(urlList.get(i)));
    }
    MediaSource mediaSource = mediaSources.length == 1 ? mediaSources[0]
            : new ConcatenatingMediaSource(mediaSources);
    player.prepare(mediaSource);
}
```

**On Video URLs Fetched**

```
@Override
public void onVideosFetched(String[] urls) {
    if (urls.length == 0) {
        showAlertAndFinish(getString(R.string.empty_video_message));
        return;
    }
    urlList.addAll(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(urls)));
    initializePlayer();
   /* if ((*//*Util.SDK_INT <= 23 ||*//* player == null)) {
        initializePlayer();
    }*/
}
```

Comment: post your player initialization code

Comment: Sorry for replying late. I have updated my question, please have a look.

Comment: why to re-initialize when you can simply reuse the same player multiple times?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are reinitializing your player in `initializePlayer()` method after `onVideosFetched(String[] urls)` method get called. But you have not assigned eventListener there.

```
private void initializePlayer() {
    simpleExoPlayerView.requestFocus();
    TrackSelection.Factory videoTrackSelectionFactory =
            new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter);
    trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(videoTrackSelectionFactory);
    player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this, trackSelector);
    simpleExoPlayerView.setPlayer(player);

    MediaSource[] mediaSources = new MediaSource[urlList.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < urlList.size(); i++) {
        mediaSources[i] = buildMediaSource(Uri.parse(urlList.get(i)));
    }
    MediaSource mediaSource = mediaSources.length == 1 ? mediaSources[0]
            : new ConcatenatingMediaSource(mediaSources);
    player.prepare(mediaSource);


    //Add lister to the player
    player.addListener(eventListener);
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Ohh, I did Silly mistake. Thank you. Can you tell me one more think please. How can I show the index like "1 form 6"

Comment: Sorry, I have not worked in exo player. Post another question for that. So someone will help you.

Comment: Its Ok. NP. Thank you :)

Comment: why to re-initialize when you can simply reuse the same player multiple times?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are using the wrong playback state constants. ExoPlayer [has 4  state constants in Player](http://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/Player.html#STATE_IDLE) which are Player.STATE_IDLE, Player.STATE_BUFFERING, Player.STATE_READY and Player.STATE_ENDED.

To detect when the player goes from one item to another in the timeline you need to use onPositionDiscontinuity rather than onPlaybackStateChanged. Something like this might do the trick:

```
int lastWindowIndex;

@Override
public void onPositionDiscontinuity(int reason) {
  int currentWindowIndex = player.getCurrentWindowIndex();
  if (reason == Player.DISCONTINUITY_REASON_PERIOD_TRANSITION) {
    if (lastPlaybackState == currentWindowIndex - 1) {
      // skipped to next
    } else if (lastPlaybackState == currentWindowIndex + 1) {
      // skipped to previous
    } else {
      // jumped more than one window index
    }
  }
  lastWindowIndex = currentWindowIndex;
  startOrUpdateNotification();
}
```